# a specific user can't mount usb sticks

Tags: usb, mount, user-management

I have the problem that a specific user can't use usb sticks any more. they are not mounted automatically any more.
For some weird reason I changed the numeric userid and groupid of this user (actually to solve some problems with a NAS).

I saved the home directory of the user in question and deleted the user.
When I create a new user with the same numeric uid but a new username, it works.
When I create a new user with the same numeric and username, it doesn't work ...

using Ubuntu 14.04

thankful for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the userid and groupid of the user you essentially "made" a new user without adding that user to the groups that the original was in. Type

```
groups
```

to see what groups a given user is in. By default on Trusty I am in the following groups:

```
eagle adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Your problem user will likely be in no groups or only the user's personal group. To add more groups you will need to use the `usermod` command as root. In order to allow usb drives to be used you will need to execute

```
usermod -Ga plugdev login_name
```

where *login_name* is the name of your user. If you want to add all the default groups, execute

```
usermod -Ga adm,cdrom,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare login_name
```

If your user was able to use the `sudo` command, also add `sudo` to the above list.